# shiny app for twitter not functioning . Need help debugging

Tags: r, twitter, shiny

I will try to be very elaborate about the issue I am facing.

My app should

- Take input from user
- Get the tweets,   clean the tweets,   find the sentiment on the
  tweets,    return sentiment scores and other values.

This is the link to the set of pos and neg words that you have to keep in your working directory before analysis. https://github.com/williamgunn/SciSentiment

This is server.R

```
     library(twitteR)
library(stringr)
library(ROAuth)
library(RCurl)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(tm)
library(RJSONIO)
library(wordcloud)
library(gridExtra)
library(plyr)
library(bitops)
library(NLP)
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

#library(shinyIncubator)
library(shiny)
#the below 2 lines of code is not required as this is obsolete and is used only with twitter cred handshake 
#load("twitteR_credentials")
#registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)

#use setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = "your key", consumer_secret = "your secret")

# Function to create a data frame from tweets
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  # Function to clean tweets, Stanton 2013
  CleanTweets<-function(tweets)
  {
    # Remove redundant spaces
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets," "," ")
    # Get rid of URLs
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets, "http://t.co/[a-z,A-Z,0-9]*{8}","")
    # Take out retweet header, there is only one
    tweets <- str_replace(tweets,"RT @[a-z,A-Z]*: ","")
    # Get rid of hashtags
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets,"#[a-z,A-Z]*","")
    # Get rid of references to other screennames
    tweets <- str_replace_all(tweets,"@[a-z,A-Z]*","")
    return(tweets)

  }

  #Search tweets and create a data frame 
  TweetFrame<-function(searchTerm, maxTweets)
  {
    twtList<-searchTwitter(searchTerm,n=maxTweets,lang="en")
    twtList1<- do.call("rbind",lapply(twtList,as.data.frame))
    twtList1$text<-iconv(twtList1$text, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII') #WILL THIS SOLVE THE UTF ENCODING PROBLEM: http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2013-May/000335.html
    return(twtList1)

  }

  # function to calculate number of tweets (input is text column, if the entire data frame was submitted, 
  #could've used nrow(), as done at a different place below)

  numoftweets<-function(entity1,entity2,entity1entry,entity2entry){
    ent1numtweets<-nrow(entity1)
    ent2numtweets<-nrow(entity2)
    notweets<-c(ent1numtweets,ent2numtweets)
    names(notweets)<-c(entity1entry,entity2entry)
    notweets
  } 


  # function for word cloud 

  wordcloudentity<-function(entitycleantext)
  {
    tweetCorpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(CleanTweets(entitycleantext)))
    tweetTDM<-TermDocumentMatrix(tweetCorpus,control=list(removePunctuation=TRUE,
                                                          stopwords=c(stopwords('english')),
                                                          removeNumbers=TRUE,tolower=TRUE))
    tdMatrix <- as.matrix(tweetTDM) # creating a data matrix
    sortedMatrix<-sort(rowSums(tdMatrix),decreasing=TRUE) # calculate row sum of each term and sort in descending order (high freq to low)
    cloudFrame<-data.frame(word=names(sortedMatrix),freq=sortedMatrix)#extracting names from named list in prev command and binding together into a dataframe with frequencies - called cloudFrame, names in separate columns

    wcloudentity<-wordcloud(cloudFrame$word,cloudFrame$freq,max.words=100, colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"),scale=c(8,1), random.order=TRUE)
    print(wcloudentity)
  }

  # Scoring sentiment expressed - Breen's algorithm
  #Jeffrey Breen: http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/twitter-text-mining-r-slides/ 
  #via Gaston Sanchez's twitter mining project: https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/sentiment/analysis   

  score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words)
  {

    # we got a vector of sentences. plyr will handle a list
    # or a vector as an "l" for us
    # we want a simple array ("a") of scores back, so we use 
    # "l" + "a" + "ply" = "laply":
    scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

      # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():
      sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence)
      sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence)
      # and convert to lower case:
      sentence = tolower(sentence)

      # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
      word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
      # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
      words = unlist(word.list)

      # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms
      pos.matches = match(words, pos.words, nomatch=NA_integer_)
      neg.matches = match(words, neg.words, nomatch=NA_integer_)

      # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
      # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:
      pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)
      neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

      # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():
      score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

      return(score)
    }, pos.words, neg.words)

    scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences, size=seq(length(scores)))
    return(scores.df)
  }

  #calling the above sentiment scoring function, the text of tweets serve as inputs

    sentimentalanalysis<-function(entity1text,entity2text,entity1entry,entity2entry){

    # A compiled list of words expressing positive and negative sentiments ----
    #http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html
    # List of words and additional information on the original source from Jeffrey Breen's github site at:
    #https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107/tree/master/data/opinion-lexicon-English

    positivewords=readLines("positive_words.txt")
    negativewords=readLines("negative_words.txt")

    #Applying score.sentiment algorithm to cleaned tweets and getting data frames of tweets, net sentiment score for a tweet 
    #(number of positive sentiments minus negative sentiments)

    entity1score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity1text),positivewords,negativewords)
    entity2score = score.sentiment(CleanTweets(entity2text),positivewords,negativewords)

    # Adding a dummy variable useful for a ggplot
    entity1score$entity = entity1entry
    entity2score$entity = entity2entry

    #combine all of this
    entityscores<-rbind(entity1score,entity2score)

  }   



  # Time for execution

  # Reading in values for the two entities
  entity1<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entity1<-TweetFrame(input$entity1, input$maxTweets)}
  )
  #entity 2
  entity2<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entity2<-TweetFrame(input$entity2, input$maxTweets)}
  )


  #Creating sentiment scores
  entityscores<-reactive({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    entityscores<-sentimentalanalysis(entity1()$text,entity2()$text,input$entity1,input$entity2)})

  #Preparing the output in a series of tabs

  #tab 1  - number of tweets for the two entities and also plotting the probability of arrival of a new tweet 
  #within a particular time t

  #number of tweets
  output$notweets<-renderPrint({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    numoftweets(entity1(),entity2(),input$entity1,input$entity2)})


  #tab 1: Not all chatter may be good. So a box plot to see the distribution of scores of sentiments 

  output$sentiboxplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    cutoff <- data.frame(yintercept=0, cutoff=factor(0))
    sentiboxplot<-ggplot(entityscores(),aes(x=size,y=score))+
      facet_grid(entity ~ .)+
      geom_point(color = "black",size = 2, alpha = 1/2)+
      geom_smooth(method = "loess",se=FALSE,col='red',size=1.5, alpha = 0.7)+
      geom_hline(aes(yintercept=yintercept, linetype=cutoff), data=cutoff)+
      xlab('Tweet number')+
      ylab('Sentiment Score')+
      theme_bw()
    print(sentiboxplot)})


  # getting a feel for how sentiments were scored by scanning 4 tweets per entity and sentiment scores - data frame entity scores shown
  output$sentiheadtable<-renderTable({tab<-head(entityscores(),4)})
  output$sentitailtable<-renderTable({tab<-tail(entityscores(),4)})

  #tab 2 - Word Clouds to highlight terms used in tweets associated with the two entities
  output$entity1wc<-renderText({

    input$entity1})
  output$entity1wcplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    wordcloudentity(entity1()$text)})

  output$entity2wc<-renderText({input$entity2})
  output$entity2wcplot<-renderPlot({
    if(input$actb>=0 ){ 
      withProgress(session, min=1, max=15, expr={
        for(i in 1:15) {
          setProgress(message = 'Calculation in progress',
                      detail = 'This may take a while...',
                      value=i)

          Sys.sleep(0.1)
        }
      })}
    wordcloudentity(entity2()$text)})


  #tab  3: Raw tweets of entity 1
  output$tableentity1 <- renderTable({tab<-entity1()[1]})

  #tab 4: Raw tweets of entity 2

  output$tableentity2<-renderTable({tab<-entity2()[1]})


})
```

This is ui.R

```
    #install.packages("shinyIncubator")
library(shiny)
#install shiny incubator using dev tools
library(shinyIncubator)

shinyUI(fluidPage(


  headerPanel("Twitter Sentiment Analysis"),

  # Getting User Inputs

  sidebarPanel(

    wellPanel(
      textInput("entity1", "Handle 1: ","#apple"),
      textInput ("entity2","Handle 2: ","#google"),
      HTML
      ("<div style='font-size: 10px;font-weight: bold'> Enter the tweet tags that you want '#'</div>")
      )  ,
    wellPanel(
      sliderInput("maxTweets","Number of recent tweets to use for analysis:",min=10,max=15000,value=20,step=1), # The max can, of course, be increased
      actionButton(inputId='actb',icon =icon("twitter"), label="Analyze!")
    )

    ),

  mainPanel(

  tabsetPanel(

      #Output from tab 4 ----So a box plot to see the distribution of scores of sentiments 
      tabPanel("Sentiment Analysis", plotOutput("sentiboxplot"), HTML
               ("<div> This plot shows the distribution of positive/negative sentiments about each entity. Note that tweets were cleaned before this analysis was performed. For each tweet, a net score of positive and negative sentiments are computed and this plot shows the distribution of scores.A higher sentiment score suggests more positive (or a less negative) discussion of that entity than the other.</div>"),
               tableOutput("sentiheadtable"),tableOutput("sentitailtable"),id="test"),

      #Output from tab 5 - Word clouds - with some html tags

      tabPanel("Word Clouds",h2(textOutput("entity1wc")),plotOutput("entity1wcplot"),h2(textOutput("entity2wc")),plotOutput("entity2wcplot")),

      #Output from tabs 6 and 7, the raw tweets
      tabPanel("Entity 1 Raw tweets",tableOutput("tableentity1")),
      tabPanel("Entity 2 Raw tweets",tableOutput("tableentity2"))
    )
  )

))
```

This is a screen shot of my ui(whose functionality is not functioning as expected)
[image]

[image]
[image]

I have not been able to debug these two errors.

- Error in value - private$min : non-numeric argument to binary operator.
- Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'environment'.

Can anybody help me with any inputs or suggestions to get this shiny app running are welcome. 
Before running the code , you should have your developer account on twitter setup.

Comment: @RichardScriven CodeReview is for code that is already **working as indended**. As such this question is not a good fit for codereview. For more information, please refer to ["A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Vogel612 - Oops!  Sorry for my confusion.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what was causing those errors. 
initially one had to use shinyincubator and the progress bars that came with it.
Now shiny has been updated and progress bars are now a part of it.

The ***withProgress()***  function was causing the bugs. By modifying it to the current syntax in shiny , the errors disappear.